# Download theme from wordpress admin area without FTP

Tags: wordpress

I am in a position where I need to download a theme from wordpress, but I don't have FTP access. Is there any way to download an entire theme from the wordpress admin.

I have looked for a plugin but have not had any luck.

Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer my own question.

You can download themes using the following plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-code-editor/

Comment: @can you tell me how you did this please

Comment: @techno I'm no longer working on this project so I forget the exact process, but as far as I remember It was as easy as installing the above plugin clicking the download theme button.

Comment: Install and enable the plugin, browse to the theme edit screen `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php` and you should see a new code editor toolbar - the icon on the far right is "Download Theme".

Comment: The download theme button is not working. Were you able to download it?

Comment: 1: Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor
2: Select Theme in the dropdown at the top right
3: Tool button bar above the editor area has a Download Theme option (last button on mine)

Comment: Yep but when click on it theme is not getting download....Its just loading and then stop loading. Haven't get any popup for downloading it..Any help?

Comment: @Kalai I had the same problem. Loading indicator starts, then stops with no action. I could download individual files but I need the whole theme. :)

Comment: `This plugin was closed on January 26, 2018 and is no longer available for download. Reason: Security Issue.` Thats on the WP Plugin page.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: Found a plugin that worked. [WP Downloader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downloader/). Worked like a charm. Downloaded, activated and the 'Download' button appeared on the Appearance page.

[image]

I tried [Theme Downloader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-downloader/), but it appears it only works with older versions of Wordpress. Many people reported that they can't find the 'download' button it is supposed to add.

I also tried [Advanced Code Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-code-editor/) but the 'Download Theme' button did not work. It would spin, and status would be 'contacting URL...' but then it would die. Download file button worked fine, but there are tons of files, and I didn't want to have to download them one by one. When I tried downloading one of the standard themes I got the error 'error zipping files' so it might be something specific to my Wordpress installation.

I also tried [Wordpress BackItUp and Restore](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-backitup/). I could not activate the theme because there was an error creating the files or folders. Once again could be a permissions related issue with my installation of Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

"Download Plugins and Themes from Dashboard" is yet another awesome plugin with Easy GUI for you to download the plugins and themes. I've used Advanced Code Editor earlier, but now I've been using this plugin since past few months.

Plugin Link - https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard/