# Download wordpress plugin from dashboard without FTP

Tags: php, ftp, wordpress

I have looked through various other topics [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347839/download-theme-from-wordpress-admin-area-without-ftp) on here, but they show how to upload plugins or download themes, but I'm wondering is there a way to download a plugin from the Wordpress Dashboard without FTP access.

There is a modified version of a plugin that I want to download and then install on another site, but I do not have FTP access to the original website, only admin access to the dashboard. Is it possible to download all the plugin files - not just the ones listed in the Plugin Editor area?

Comment: You cannot get access to the source code files without some form of access to the underlying file system (ftp, ssh etc). If you can somehow copy the files you want to a public directory and give them a `.txt` file extension, or otherwise somehow persuade the webserver not to pass them to PHP (given that it's wordpress I'm sure there are security holes a-plenty that would allow you to do this), then you can copy paste them through the browser - but this is a crappy solution. Best advice would be to contact the server admin and obtain the source files properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of this  plugin you can download any plugin from your dashboard https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugin/. Follow the below steps

1. Just activate this plugin.
2. You can see Download link below each plugin name on plugins page.
3. Click on any of them and that plugin’s zip will be
4. downloaded to your computer.
5. You are done :)

Comment: Looks like the plugin has been discontinued

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Plugin and Theme Editor turned off in WordPress, another alternative is installing a backup plugin such as [Updraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) or [BackWPUp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/) or using your existing backup system and using that to download a copy of all files including plugin files.